# Convert RPM file to ISO file

Tags: iso, conversion, rpm

I want to download an OS. I have two options:

- either downloading `ISO` file  directly via remote link.

  Or
- Downloading `RPM` package via `BitTorrent`

I want to download via `BitTorrent`. However, I want to get an `ISO` file .

The issue is how to convert this `RPM` package to `ISO` image file.

Comment: You can download Ubuntu ISO over a torrent from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads RPM = Redhat = off topic. And you can not get an OS in RPM format?! Redhat provides ISOs (though these seem to be on not so legal websites :))

Comment: it is another OS.

Comment: Which one? I find giving as much information on these forums is better as there might actually be a better way to do what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu, we don"t use RPM (RedHat) packages but DEB (Debian) packages.

If you have an ISO file, you have thus a CD-ROM image you can use to install the OS on a PC where the OS is not yet installed.
If you have packages (one package = one software, one OS is composed of a multitude of packages), you need at least to have an running installation of the OS to which these packages belong to proceed further.